# Border not covering whole site - elements out of flow?

Tags: html, css

Problem:

https://postimg.cc/image/tunhwh8qj/

The trouble I am currently having is that the border around my body is not outlining everything. As I have recently learned I'm guessing this means an element is out of the flow due to floating? However I am not certain how to fix it in this case.

My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swaggersstyle.css">
        <title>Oamaru Backpackers Hostel, Swaggers Backpackers - Home</title>
    
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- include Cycle plugin --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
    
    
<body>
    <img src="final.jpg" id="banner">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="planning.html">Location</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="construction.html">Facilities</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="evaluation.html">Attractions</a></li>
        <li id = "endlink"><a href="evaluation.html" id="lastlink">Bookings</a></li>
    </ul>


<div id="leftcolumn">
<p>hghadgadgadg</p>
<p>easfasf</p>
<p>safSFS</p>
<p>afafafadf</p>
<p>safasf</p>
<p>saasfasf</p>
<p>fasfsaf</p>
</div>
    
<div id="mainc">

    <p>Make Yourself at Home</p>
    <p>Swaggers Backpackers is a converted old house located within     walking distance of all the best parts of Oamaru. Explore the old   victorian era buildings and shops of the city centre, or see the    penguin colonies down the street. Swaggers is owned and operated    by camp mum Agra, who makes all guests feel welcome, informed,  and perhaps a bit mothered. </p>

    <div class="slideshow"> 
        <img src="1.jpg" width="600" height="450" /> 
        <img src="2.jpg" width="600" height="450" /> 
        <img src="3.jpg" width="600" height="450" /> 
    </div> 


</div>   



<div id ="footer">
<p> fsafasfasf </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS is:

```
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color:#464E54;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#banner{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
    border-top: 1px solid #7f7f7f;

}

#mainc {
    float: left;
    width: 654px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    height: 100%;
}

#leftcolumn {
    padding-left: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    width: 290px;
    border-right: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0.5px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    border-top: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

#footer p{
    margin: 0;
}

.links {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

#endlink {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border-right: none;
}

#lastlink{
    display: block;
    width: 184px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#lastlink:hover{
    background-color: #999999;
}

a:link {

    display: block;
    width: 183px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

a:visited {

    display: block;
    width: 183px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #999999;
}

a:active{
    background-color: #999999;
}

.slideshow {
    height: 483px;
    width: 632px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.slideshow img {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: You're still using the `float` property for several styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because your body has fix height of 100%.Change body tag css as:

```
height:auto;
min-height: 100%
```

if this doesn't work then add following with this:

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: Hey mate I added this code and now I have the following: http://postimage.org/image/2e6gj4rj8/

Comment: It has fixed the border problem however what I now need is for the left column to fill the whole length of the page also.

Comment: Ye the min-height breaks any child with %height. You should redo your design and give a border to the content area, a white background for the content and a general brown background so it will show under the menu

Comment: @AndyNZ: Simple hack will be giving same background color to container(in your case body tag) as left column that is `#dad8bf`(I think so) or try [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/). Also take a look at this one: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Any_Column_Longest

Comment: I checked out the Faux Columns link and now I've fixed it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Probably better NOT to use the `body` element for your container. Instead, just add

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

around your code and in your CSS change`html` to `body` and `body` to `div.container`.

```
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color:#464E54;
    height: 100%;
}

div.container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I completely missed the 100%, that's gotta be it.

Comment: Hey mate I changed my code to what you have reccomended and I have ended up with this result (same as above):

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/2e6gj4rj8/ What is your opinion on my best option to make my left column go down the whole length of the page? cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow: hidden to your body element. When elements are floated it will not push the parent container height past it unless there is a clearer